# Textbox only displays temporarily after javascript function runs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I would like to show/hide a textbox when the user clicks a filter icon in the header of a gridview.  Initially, the textbox is hidden.  When I click the icon, the textbox appears for a second then it looks like the page is refreshed and the textbox is hidden again.
This is the HTML:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Group Name">
<HeaderTemplate> Group Name
    <asp:ImageButton ID="uggvGroupFilter" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/filter.png" OnClientClick="ShowHideFilterTxtBox('uggvTxtNameFilter')" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="uggvTxtNameFilter" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" style="display:none;" ClientIDMode="Static" OnTextChanged="uggvGridFilter_TextChanged">
    </asp:TextBox>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="uggvLblGroupName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GroupName") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the javascript function:

```
function ShowHideFilterTxtBox(filterID) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(filterID);
  if (obj.style.display == "none") {
    obj.style.display = "block";         
  } else {
    obj.style.display = "none";               
  }
}
```

This is my document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Configure the DropDownBox using the 'chosen' jquery plugin
  $(".chosen-single").chosen({
    search_contains: true,
    width: "200px",
    no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!"
  });         
});
```

Do I need to put something in my document ready function also?
Why is the style of the textbox only set for a second and then returning to the original style display which is 'none'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `return false` in your client side function.

```
function ShowHideFilterTxtBox(filterID) {
        var obj = document.getElementById(filterID);
        if (obj.style.display == "none") {
            obj.style.display = "block";         
        }
        else {
            obj.style.display = "none";               
        }
    return false;
 }
```

And when you call

```
OnClientClick="return ShowHideFilterTxtBox('uggvTxtNameFilter')"
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked.  Originally, I had a `return false` but not the `return` in the `OnClientClick`.  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: If it works without the return in OnClientClick, just remove it. :)

Comment: No.  I needed both for it to work.  I was just wondering why the function needed a return.  That' all.